# Fatal error : Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in

Tags: php

I am an android developer. I am not well versed in php. I tried to launch my control panel for my app. However, after I uploaded my files and put in my login credentials, I had this error.

> Fatal error
>   : Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in login_form.php
>   on line
>   45

My code from this page is as follows:

```
<?php   
include_once('includes/variables.php');
// start session
//session_start();

// if user click Login button
if(isset($_POST['btnLogin'])){

    // get username and password
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // set time for session timeout
    $currentTime = time() + 25200;
    $expired = 3600;

    // create array variable to handle error
    $error = array();

    // check whether $username is empty or not
    if(empty($username)){
        $error['username'] = "*Username should be filled.";
    }

    // check whether $password is empty or not
    if(empty($password)){
        $error['password'] = "*Password should be filled.";
    }

    // if username and password is not empty, check in database
    if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)){

        // change username to lowercase
        $username = strtolower($username);

        //encript password to sha256
        $password = hash('sha256',$username.$password);

        // get data from user table
        $sql_query = "SELECT * 
            FROM tbl_user 
            WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";

        $stmt = $connect->stmt_init();
        if($stmt->prepare($sql_query)) {
            // Bind your variables to replace the ?s
            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
            // Execute query
            $stmt->execute();
            /* store result */
            $stmt->store_result();
            $num = $stmt->num_rows;
            // Close statement object
            $stmt->close();
            if($num == 1){
                $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['timeout'] = $currentTime + $expired;
                header("location: dashboard.php");
            }else{
                $error['failed'] = "<span class='blue-text text-darken-2'>Login failed</span>";
            }
        }

    }   
}
?>
<body class="teal">
    <main>
    <br>
    <div class="login-container">
      <div class="col s12">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
                  <div class="section center">                  <h5 class="text-center">Login Administrator</h5>
                    <p><?php echo isset($error['failed']) ? $error['failed'] : '';?></p>
                  </div>

                    <form method="post">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="input-field col s12">                   
                                <input type="text" class="validate" name="username" id="username" required>
                                <label for="username">Username</label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="input-field col s12">                       
                                <input type="password" class="validate" name="password" id="password" required>
                                <label for="password">Password</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                            <input type="submit" name="btnLogin" class="btn-primary btn right" value="Login"><br><br>       
                    </form>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </main>
```

variables code is :

```
<?php

    //database configuration

    $host       = "localhost";
    $user       = "root";
    $pass       = "";
    $database   = "android_news_app";

    $connect    = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $database) or die("Error : ".mysql_error());      

?>
```

Can anyone be any assistance to me?

Comment: The $connect variable does not seem to be initialized. Is it initialized in variables.php? And is it a valid connection instance?

Comment: @RSingh update Qustion added Variables Code

Comment: There's no need to call `stmt_init`. Just use `$stmt = $connect->prepare()`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

PHP raised this error because, the member function called on the non-object. The issue because to initialization of object my_sqli is not done properly. Before calling prepare method, the object must be initialized and  connection should parameters must be passed appropriately so, it creates successful connection and returns object.

`$host = "my_host"; //"localhost" or "http://mysql.host.com"
$user = "my_username"; //an authorized user of the MySQL database
$password = "my_password"; //my_username's password
$database = "my_database"; //the database we want to use.
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) 
{
die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
if ($stmt->prepare("some valid SQL query")) 
{
    $stmt->bind_params("s...", $vars); 
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $stmt->bind_result($vars);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        //do stuff with the data
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
$mysqli->close();`

Answer (score -1):

Try to change this two lines

```
$stmt = $connect->stmt_init();
if($stmt->prepare($sql_query)) {
```

for this

```
if ($stmt = $connect->prepare($sql_query)) {
```

Comment: @HamzahAbdullah sorry?

Comment: This worked so well and it was the first answer. Why the downvote?

Comment: it's not work the form doesn't make login when I was used it